# How to disable past dates without hiding them in Kendo date picker?

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker

If I set min value for the date picker, it does not display dates less than min date when it's opened.

My requirement is that dates less than min date should be shown in the date picker, but they should be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with CSS styles and using custom content in Kendo datepicker.

HTML:

```
<input id="datepicker" style="width:150px;" />
```

CSS:

```
.disabledDay { 
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 0 .45em 0 .1em;
    cursor:default;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

disabledDaysBefore = [
  +new Date("10/20/2014")
];

var p = $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
      value: new Date(),
      dates: disabledDaysBefore,
      month: {
          content: '# if (data.date < data.dates) { #' +    
          '<div class="disabledDay">#= data.value #</div>' +
          '# } else { #' +
          '#= data.value #' +
          '# } #'
      },
      open: function(e){
          $(".disabledDay").parent().removeClass("k-link")
          $(".disabledDay").parent().removeAttr("href")
      },
     }).data("kendoDatePicker");

});
```

See demo:
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ps48vxu9/)

Comment: +1 for nice answer.But user is still able to select those disabled dates through manual/keyboard input :)

Comment: you can also minify the open event code by `$("a.k-link:has('.disabledDay')").removeClass("k-link").removeAttr("href");`

Answer (score 3):

All credit to devlero on this one, I was able to convert this to Razor Syntax, if anyone would like to use that instead.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("datepicker")
          .Value(DateTime.Today)
          .Events(e => e.Open("onOpen"))
          .MonthTemplate("# if (data.date < disabledDaysBefore) { #" +
                                "<div class='disabledDay'>#= data.value #</div>" +
                             "# } else { #" +
                "#= data.value #" +
                "# } #")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 150px;" })      
    )


 $(document).ready(function () {                         
        disabledDaysBefore = [
          +new Date("10/20/2014")
        ];      
    });

function onOpen() {
            $(".disabledDay").parent().removeClass("k-link")
            $(".disabledDay").parent().removeAttr("href")
        }
```

Comment: you can also minify the onOpen function code by `$("a.k-link:has('.disabledDay')").removeClass("k-link").removeAttr("href");`