# How to disable the past dates in the Kendo date picker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to disable the past dates in the Kendo date picker ? ( Date Picker validation)

That will allow the user to select only the current date and future date.

```
In the HTML :
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.AppointmentDate)

In the JQuery :
$('#AppointmentDatee').data('kendoDatePicker')
```

Comment: Can you provide snippet of the Kendo date picker code? At least it should comply with [mcve].

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto,  sorry for that. please take a look on the syntax

Comment: I think easier to use `Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Min(DateTime.Now)` or `Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Min(DateTime.Today)`. Also I want to ask this: are you want to hide all disabled past dates or just show but disable click on them?

Comment: Either way , it is fine. Objective is to select either today’s or future date. Not the past date. I was hoping to make the changes on html editor .  Having kendo datepicker syntax actually changes the date format or design format.

Comment: I decided to include both of them (hiding all past dates & grayed-out disabled dates). The implementation parts are somewhat similar, just with little difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shortest way to disable past dates is using `min` parameter with current date value:

```
var presentDate = new Date();

$(function () {
    var datepicker = $('#AppointmentDate').kendoDatePicker({
        value: presentDate,
        min: presentDate,
    }).data('kendoDatePicker');
});
```

If you're using Razor with `@Html.Kendo()` helper, use [`DatePickerBuilderBase.Min()`](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DatePickerBuilderBase#minsystemdatetime) method:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("AppointmentDate").Min(DateTime.Today))
```

However, the `min` parameter will remove all disabled past dates (i.e. they're not shown in calendar view). If you want to show disabled dates but the user cannot interact with them (by clicking the date), use `k-state-disabled` CSS class in `empty` option inside `month` parameter:

```
var datepicker = $('#AppointmentDate2').kendoDatePicker({
        value: presentDate,
    min: presentDate,
    month: {
        empty: '<div class="k-state-disabled">#= data.value #</div>'
    }
}).data('kendoDatePicker');
```

If `@(Html.Kendo())` helper is used, use `DisabledDates` to call a function which disables past dates like example below:

```
<script>
var getPastDates = function(begin, end) {
    for (var dtarr = [], date = start; date < end; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
        dtarr.push(new Date(dt));
    }

    return dtarr;
}

function disablePastDates(date) {
    var pastDate = getPastDates(new Date('0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'), new Date());
    if (date && compareDates(date, dates)) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function compareDates(date, dates) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (dates[i].getDate() == date.getDate() &&
            dates[i].getMonth() == date.getMonth() &&
            dates[i].getYear() == date.getYear()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Helper usage:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("AppointmentDate").DisableDates("disablePastDates"))
```

Working examples:

[JSFiddle demo 1 (hidden past dates)](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/824979/)

[JSFiddle demo 2 (grayed-out past dates)](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/824980/)

References:

[Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DatePickerBuilderBase.Min(DateTime)](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DatePickerBuilderBase#minsystemdatetime)

[Show Out-of-Range Dates as Disabled](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/how-to/show-out-of-range-dates-in-disabled-style)

[Kendo MVC DatePicker - Disable dates](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/disable-dates)

Similar issue (with different approach):

[How to disable past dates without hiding them in Kendo date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484563/how-to-disable-past-dates-without-hiding-them-in-kendo-date-picker)

Comment: Best well detailed explanation;

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery for your kendoDatePicker , this code may help you!

```
$("#MyDatapickerElement").kendoDatePicker({
        value: new Date(),
        disableDates: function (date) {
            if (date <= new Date()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Html.Kendo().DatePicker() you can show the disabled dates using the MonthTemplate. Example below shows the Minimum Date set to DateTime.Today and sets the MonthTemplate to show past dates as disabled.

```
Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
            .Name("MyDate")
            .Min(DateTime.Today)
            .MonthTemplate(m=>m
            .Empty("<div class=\"k-state-disabled\">#= data.value #</div>")
             )
```